# C# Word Interop Reading Issue

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have an Interop problem that I just cannot solve...

I am trying to read and store a Word document page by page. The document in questions contains a table that runs over 2 pages. When it comes to reading this table, the entire table is being read and stored as a single page (twice). What I want to achieve is to have half the table on page x and the other half on page y.

```
    List<string> pages = new List<string>();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object objSaveOption = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    object readOnly = true;
    object includeFootnotesAndEndnotes = true;
    object path = @"C:\FileLocation";
    WdStatistic stat1 = WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word1.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
    int numberOfPages = docs.ComputeStatistics(stat1, ref miss);    // Gets the number of pages
    var document1 = word1.ActiveDocument;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        document1.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Go to page "i"
       .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, i, miss);


        document1.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Select whole page
       .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark, miss, miss, "\\page").Copy();

        pages.Add(Clipboard.GetText());
    }


    docs.Close(ref objSaveOption);
    word1.Quit();
```

I have narrowed the problem down to these 2 statements. When I go to page 'i', is there a way to only select the information that is stored on that page, and not info that flows over onto the next page?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sam, i've tested your code and it works as expected. I've created document with two pages and table that flows across the two pages, then i paste the content of each page to a new document and table and the rest of the content is selected correctly and splited across different pages without any dublication. Is it possible to have some expanding logic of the selection somewhere between the lines you have posted in the question ?

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks a lot for getting back to me and for trying it out! It's encouraging that you have got it to work. I have edited my original post with a more detailed version of the code. Is there anything you can see here which would be causing the problem? (Thanks again)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue can be related to this part

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
```

Pages in MsWord starts from 1 (they are not 0 based), if you change your code to

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
```

this way it will go from page 1 to the last. There is chance the issue to be resolved probably.

With your current code you iterate page 0 (which will return page 1) and page 1 and you skip the last page.